# Can grep highlight matching text without hiding file content?

Tags: command-line

I frequently use `grep`'s context command line options (`-A`, `-B`, and `-C`), but occasionally I want to view the whole file with matching expressions highlighted. To accomplish this currently I simply specify `-C 999999999`, but this seems silly.

Is there an option within OS X's bundled `grep` that will allow me to easily take advantage of grep's matching and colorizing features, without hiding any file content?

Comment: I say "OS X's bundled `grep`" explicitly because I know that this is BSD `grep`, and I would rather not install GNU's whole coreutils, assuming GNU `grep` has this built in.

Comment: I don't think the bundled grep is capable of this. OTOH you could `alias grep='/usr/bin/grep -C 999999999'` in interactive shells and forget about it.

Comment: This is not intended to be a permanent change :). (Translation: `alias grepall='/usr/bin/grep -C 999999999'`)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I don't think there is any simple option in grep but this seems to work fine. From https://stackoverflow.com/a/981831

```
grep --color -E "pattern|$" file
```

The `|$` at the end of the regular expression makes grep find pattern OR end of lines. It can't highlight those though, so just the pattern gets colored.

Comment: Also; `-E "pattern.*|$"` will highlight until the end of the line.

Comment: For example: `ls /bin/ /usr/bin/ |sort |grep --colour -nE '/.*|$'`

Answer (score 6):

Assuming you want to read the file yourself, with the bits highlighted, [less](http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2010/02/unix-less-command-10-tips-for-effective-navigation/) is the better tool for the job.  `less yourfile`, type `/`, your pattern and hit return.  `n` goes to the next match and `space` to the next page.

Alternatively, [ack](http://betterthangrep.com/) has a `--passthru` mode that does what you want.  ack is so insanely useful it's worth looking into.

Comment: I love this answer, and may switch to ack eventually. But in the interim, grep is so insanely ingrained in my brain that it's a hard switch to make. But thank you for this wonderful alternative.

Answer (score 2):

Setting `-C` to a negative integer seems to be equivalent to setting it an arbitrarily large number.

```
grep something --color -C -1 *.txt
```

But as with something like `-C 9999999`, if the file has multiple matches, some lines can be printed multiple times.